# Mongo DB aggregation lookup match

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections, a collection with user_message and a collection with messages. In ***messages*** the documents look like this:

```
 "_id": ObjectId("...")
"message":{
start_date:date
end_date:date
active:bool,
id:int}
```

In ***user_message*** collection look like this :

```
 "_id": ObjectId("...")
"message_id":string
```

What I want to do is an aggregation in the `user_message` collection where I add a $lookup stage to the pipeline where I go inside the messages collection and get the message where `message.id` equal `message_id` and i want to get the messages when `active` is true and the time now greater then `start_date` and less then `end_date`

my attempt :

```
 let user_id = req.query.user_id;
    let dateTime = new Date();
    dateTime = moment(dateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    let messages =
      await db
      .collection('user_message')
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            user_id: user_id
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup:{
            from:"messages",
            localField:"message.id",
            foreignField:"message_id",
            as:"messages"
          }
        },
        {
           $match:{
            'messages.message.active': '1',
            'messages.message.end_date': {
              $gte: dateTime
            },
          'message.start_date': {
            $lte: dateTime
          }
           }
        },
        {
          $project:{
          messages: 1,
          }
        }
    ])
    .toArray();
```

and i want the result to be like this :

```
      message:{start_at:date,
               end_date:date,
                active:boo},
    _id: ObjectId("...")
   ]
```

Comment: Can you provide some more sample documents and what you want your expected output to be?  I'm wondering if it would make more sense to perform the aggregation on the messages collection instead of the user_message collection.  You could perform the match stage first on the messages collection and then perform the lookup.

Comment: @LaurenSchaefer I have modified the question

Comment: Instead of `moment(dateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` you should better use `moment().toDate()` in order to compare real `Date` values rather than strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.  I'm not sure how many messages will be in a message document or if more than one user_message will match a message document.  But here is what I came up with.  The pipeline is executed on the messages collection:

```
[
{$match: {
  "message.active": true,
  "message.start_date": {
    $gte: ISODate('2020-01-01T05:00:00.000+00:00')
  },
  "message.end_date": {
    $lte: ISODate('2020-01-05T05:00:00.000+00:00')
  }
}}, 
{$lookup: {
  from: 'user_messages',
  localField: 'message.id',
  foreignField: 'message_id',
  as: 'user_message'
}}]
```

This results in a document like the following:

```
_id:5e72155678117090fea3e141
message:Object
  start_date:2020-01-01T05:00:00.000+00:00
  end_date:2020-01-02T05:00:00.000+00:00
  active:true
  id:"message1"
user_message:Array
  0:Object
    _id:5e7214e71c9d44000080c1c9
    message_id:"message1"
    another_field:"hello"
```

You could add a $project stage to clean up the results to be in the format you'd like.

Comment: just I have a problem, i want to match user_id from query_string and user_id from user_message collection!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "match user_id from query_string".  Also, I don't see "user_id" in your "user_message" document.